# Easy and fast to edit and publish sharepoint 2013

Tags: document-library, page-layout

I am new to sharepoint and want to know what sharepoint 2013 offers oob to make it easy and fast to publish documents, and pages

Answer (score 0):

"Publishing" can mean different things to different people.  If by "publishing" you mean "sharing" then sharing documents is as easy as uploading them to one or more document libraries that your users have access to.  What SharePoint 2013 brings compared to previous versions is the ability to drag-and-drop files into libraries.

With pages, SharePoint has various types of pages (site pages/web part pages, wiki pages, and publishing pages).  These all function generally the same way.  You navigate the library where the pages are store, click create new page, select a layout (depends on the page type) and then add text, html and/or web part content and save.  Again, if you mean "sharing" then saving the page will make these pages available to users that have access.

Beyond that you also have the various features that apply to management of documents and pages within SharePoint including versioning, permissions, metadata, check in and check out, etc..